# In any sort of way/ in any way

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

I'm trying to construct a sentence, but I can't describe it clearly in English according to what I'm really trying to say. First off, the english words that I find malicious-worthy:

- to **jack up** (to increase, to raise, and the like...)
- to **jerk off** (a sexual reference to a man... you know this)

So, let's say you have used ''jack up'' in a sentence when speaking with a *non-native speaker*, but you have nagging doubt that it may be rude due to it sounding like ''jerk off''. Then you *researched* it *online*, and fortunately, there is *no sexual connection* to it. And you say:

> ''I've already looked it up online, carefully and thoroughly, and there is no sexual reference to it **in any sort of way** wherever website I've visited.

And

> ''I've already looked it up online, carefully and thoroughly, and there is no sexual reference to it **in any way** wherever website I've visited.

Are the bold letters really **exist** in English?, I must have heard them from somewhere. Moreover, the google results can't provide a clear explanation if there is ''in any sort of way'' or "in any way".

P.S.: there is a slight correlation between my question and the other question topics on this website, but those links were asking a different type of query.

Comment: "wherever website" is not grammatical.

Comment: There is no reference to it in any sort of way or in any way that makes sense. That's how to use "in any sort of way", for example. **Do** the bold letters exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could say

> ... with X, there's no reference whatsoever to ________.
>
> ... X does not refer in any way to ________

P.S. The phrase **in any way**  is an adjunct of manner, hence "adverbial" in nature.  So you could say

> The phrase 'jack up' **does not refer in any way** to activity of a sexual nature.

And the word **whatsoever** is a descriptive adjunct that means "of any kind", and so it is "adjectival" in nature.  So you can say

> With 'jack up' there is **no reference whatsoever** of a sexual nature.

Comment: ''I've already researched 'jack up' online, carefully and thoroughly, and there is no sexual reference to 'jerk off' whatsoever. -is this what you mean?

Comment: @John Arvin: Please see the P.S.  where I elaborate on what I was trying to show you with those two examples, one using the noun **reference** and the other using the verb **refer**.